# Spring security - implement oauth2 sso

Tags: java, spring-security, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, spring-security-oauth2

I want to implement **central authentication system with spring security and oauth2 sso**. In other words, I have a spring boot application that is responsible for authorization and one simple client. My client has rest API. First I get token from the authorization server, then send a request to client API with an authorization header contains bearer token from above request. But this request always gets me **server login page**.

Here is the implementation of the server and the client:

> **`Server`**

**`AuthorizationServerConfig.java`**

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;


@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
    oauthServer
            .tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()")
            .checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
}



@Override
public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
    clients.inMemory()
            .withClient("SampleClientId")
            .secret("{noop}secret")
            .authorizedGrantTypes("password")
            .scopes("user_info")
            .autoApprove(true);
}

@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
    endpoints.authenticationManager(this.authenticationManager);
}
```

**`ApplicationConfig:`**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableResourceServer
public class ApplicationConfig extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(ApplicationConfig.class, args);
}

}
```

**`SecurityConfig:`**

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    //this is just example
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("{noop}1234").roles("user");
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.requestMatchers()
            .antMatchers("/login", "/oauth/authorize", "/oauth/token")
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin().permitAll();

}

@Bean
@Override
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}
```

**`application.yml:`**

```
server:
  port: 8900
  servlet:
    context-path: /auth
```

> **`Client:`**

**`ApplicationConfig:`**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ApplicationConfig {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(ApplicationConfig.class, args);
}

}
```

**`SecurityConfig:`**

```
@Configuration
@EnableOAuth2Sso
public class ApplicationSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/", "/login**")
            .permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated();
}
}
```

**`TestController:`**

```
@RestController
public class HomeController {

@GetMapping("/")
public String index() {
    return "home";
}

@RequestMapping("/admin")
public String admin() {
    return "admin";
}
}
```

**`application.yml:`**

```
server:
  port: 9000
  servlet:
    context-path: /client1
security:
  basic:
    enabled: false
  oauth2:
    client:
      clientId: SampleClientId
      clientSecret: secret
      accessTokenUri: http://localhost:8900/auth/oauth/token
      userAuthorizationUri: http://localhost:8900/auth/oauth/authorize
    resource:
      userInfoUri: http://localhost:8900/auth/user/me
```

First, I send client_id and secret code along side with username, password and grant_type to `localhost:8900/auth/oauth/token` and get a result like this:

```
{
  "access_token": "603b505f-e701-43d0-b8b8-976a2178f7ea",
  "token_type": "bearer",
  "expires_in": 43199,
  "scope": "user_info"
}
```

Now, I pickup above token and send a request to `localhost:9000/client1/admin`
with header contains above token. But it seems the client application ignores the header and shows server login page as result. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@EnableOAuth2Sso` is an annotation for using OAuth 2.0 as an end-user authentication mechanism (e.g. "A Login with Google" button). This annotation is wiring your app to redirect to a login page on your authorization server where you would log in and then get redirected back to your app.

If this is your intent, then you'll need to [update your Authorization Server to support the `authorization_code` grant flow](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-oauth-authorization-code-flow) instead of the `password` grant flow.

However, if your client is strictly a REST API, then you are more likely to need to wire the client using `@EnableResourceServer` instead of `@EnableOAuth2Sso`. [A Resource Server](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-oauth2-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-security-oauth2-resource-server) is what takes a token as authorization, via the Authorization HTTP header.

Comment: Thank you. Using `@EnableResourceServer` instead of `@EnableOAuth2Sso` solved my problem.